# single underscore before function name in single-file python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

Should I use underscore before function name in single-file simple python script?
For example, in this script should I add underscore before definition of `f` and `g`? This script *won't* be imported from other files.

```py
def f(x): # or _f(x)?
    return x * 2

def g(x): # or _g(x)?
    return x ** 2

def main():
    x = f(100)
    print(g(x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I read many documents about usage of underscores in python. Many of them says underscores are about OOP-style programming and how `import` statement works. However, in simple one-file script, I can't find good answer.

What is better pattern?

Comment: Generally speaking leading underscores are meant to indicate "weak internal use". See [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id34) for more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: @JanWilamowski I already read the the answer, but I can't judge the functions in my tiny script are _weak internal use_. How can I choose it?

Comment: That only matters once you combine multiple modules and you want to hide certain aspects of your implementation. It's not necessary in your simple case.

Comment: @minty99, once your dubts are answered, you can accept the most suitable answer (or at least one that worked for you) so that others can be sure that it's a working answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular programming languages (such as `Java` and `C`/`C++`) have this kind of syntax to declare `private` `attribute`s and `method`s of a class instance:

```
class MyClass {
    private:
        int _function() {
            // Some code here
        }
    public:
        bool _foo() {
            // Some code here
        }
}
```

`Python` doesn't have (and will probably never have) a syntax like this, so they simply create a conventional name to make developers understand that a `method` is `private` and should never be accessed from outside the class.

---

According to [`PEP-8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> We don't use the term "private" here, since no attribute is really private in Python (without a generally unnecessary amount of work).

According to [`Python 2`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) and [`Python 3`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) class documentation:

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API **(whether it is a function, a method or a data member)**.

---

Using `_` may be useful for a tecnique explained below.

According to `Python 3` [class documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling.

---

NOTE: The Python documentation mostly talks about *"internal use"* referring to classes, but it can be referred to `module`s too, for example:

```
# main.py
import myModule
functionThatCanBeImported()

# myModule.py
def functionThatCanBeImported(): pass
def _functionThatShouldNeverBeImported(): pass
```

If somebody creates a `package`, they don't have to put `private` functions in the documentation, since they are for *internal scope* and explainations about them could be useful only to developers.

Comment: However I didn't use classes in my tiny script - because I think it is overkill. How to judge a function is private in this usage?

Comment: @minty99, nice question, I've just edited the answer, hope I've been helpful

Comment: Since I will not import my standalone script from other files, all functions except `main` should be single underscored, right? How do you think about this?

Comment: If you are writing a program that will never be imported by anyone there's nothing wrong with writing all without underscores.

Answer (score 1):

_ is used to let developers know that the variables and methods are private and should not be modified externally. So use _ if you want to keep the functionality within the class.

> NOTE: using _ will not restrict the use of these methods or variables though, it's just a way of representation.

Comment: However I don't use classes in my script. (just small script..)
How can I judge the function is _internal_ ?